# Find an orthonormal basis which includes the vectors $u_1 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 0)$ and $u_2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I have to find an orthonormal basis for $ \Bbb R^4
$ which includes the vectors $u_1 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 0)$ and $u_2 = (\frac{-1}2, \frac1 2,\frac1 2, \frac{-1}2)$

I really do not know how to do it, I tried to use the Gram-Schmidt method but when I started with $u_1$ then obtained $u_2$.

Any ideas?

Comment: First, find two vectors $u_3$ and $u_4$ which are perpendicular to $u_1$ and $u_2$. Then do Gram-Schmidt on $u_3$ and $u_4$ (to get $u_3$ and $v_4$). Now you will have an orthogonal basis. Then normalize $u_3$ and $v_4$ (to get $w_3$ and $w_4$); then $\{ u_1,u_2,w_3, w_4\}$ will be an orthonormal basis.

Comment: How can I find the two vectors u3 and u4 which are perpendicular to $u_1$  and $u_2$.

Comment: Set up a system of linear equations, solve it, and then parameterize the solutions. If you write your solution in vector form $x = ru + sv$, then $u$ and $v$ will be perpendicular to $u_1$ and $u_2$ (and be linearly independent).

Comment: You really only need two vectors that together with $u_1$ and $u_2$ form a linearly independent set. G-S will crank out perpendicular vectors. You could choose $(1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0,0)$, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the normalization constants, the vectors can be 
$\left(1,0,1,0\right)$, $\left(-1,1,1,-1\right)$, $\left(0,1,0,1\right)$,
$\left(-1,-1,1,1\right)$